# Got evaluating a2.metadata.unicode.widths error after add custom font in jsPdf

Tags: jspdf

I have add a custom font which download from server in jsPdf.

doc.addFileToVFS(fontName, fontBase64.split("data:application/octet-stream;base64,")[1]);
doc.addFont(fontName, fontName.split(".")[0], 'normal');

After I added custom font, the generate process is working well in PC but not working in mobile side.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTOS4.png)

I guess this error related to measure text width with custom font.

The generate process is working if I comment out the doc.addFont line, but then I can't get the font I expect.

Comment: looks like it's an iOS issue. Test in iOS 16.3.1, 16.1 not working.But working in on iOS 16.2, 16.14.1(latest version).